# GeoIP not showing all info

Tags: php

so i have this error , i downloaded the lastest
 geoipcity.inc | geoipregionvars.inc | GeoLiteCity.dat

so here is my code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Querying against GeoIP/Lite City
 * This will fetch country along with city information
 */

include("geoipcity.inc");
include("geoipregionvars.php");

$giCity = geoip_open("GeoLiteCity.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

$ip = "99.99.99.99";
$record = geoip_record_by_addr($giCity, $ip);

echo "Getting Country and City detail by IP Address <br /><br />";

echo "IP: " . $ip . "<br /><br />";

echo "Country Code: " . $record->country_code .  "<br />" .
     "Country Code3: " . $record->country_code . "<br />" .
     "Country Name: " . $record->country_name . "<br />" .
     "Region Code: " . $record->region . "<br />" .
     "City: " . $record->city . "<br />" .
     "Postal Code: " . $record->postal_code . "<br />" .
     "Latitude: " . $record->latitude . "<br />" .
     "Longitude: " . $record->longitude . "<br />" .
     "Metro Code: " . $record->metro_code . "<br />" .
     "Area Code: " . $record->area_code . "<br />" ; 

geoip_close($giCity);

?>
```

and here is my problem that 
not all resulst are shown :

1. Country Code: SA
2. Country Code3: SA
3. Country Name: Saudi Arabia
4. Region Code:
5. City:
6. Postal Code:
7. Latitude: 25
8. Longitude: 45
9. Metro Code:
10. Area Code:

Comment: Try `var_dump($record);` to see all that it contains. Maybe not all information is available.

Comment: Have a long time to do with GeoIP but chances are these informations are just missing from database. Did you tested with a real ip?